# DoHeatmap function Seurat - Error in dataframe: arguments imply differing number of rows

Tags: r, heatmap, seurat

I'm trying to use the DoHeatmap function in Seurat to show expression of a number of genes across some defined clusters.
B_cells is my Seurat object.

```
tfs <- c("PRDM1", "PAX5", "BACH2")

DoHeatmap(B_cells, features=tfs)
```

I'm getting this error back;

```
Error in data.frame(group = sort(x = group.use), x = x.divs) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10411, 0
```

When I look at the number of rows and columns in the Seurat object;

```
nrow(B_cells) = 19651

ncol(B_cells) = 10151
```

Sorry if this is a silly question but I've been stuck on it for a while now.

edit traceback():

```
3: stop(gettextf("arguments imply differing number of rows: %s", 
       paste(unique(nrows), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)
2: data.frame(group = sort(x = group.use), x = x.divs)
1: DoHeatmap(B_cells, features = genes)
```

Comment: Are those features in your rownames, do  table(tfs %in% rownames(B_cells))

Comment: Yep, it returns TRUE 3

Comment: Can you run `traceback()` immediately after the error and post the output in the question?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code for the DoHeatmap() function can be found at https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/blob/develop/R/visualization.R.  The traceback() shows line 363 of `visualization.R` is causing the error:

```
if (label) {
   x.max <- max(pbuild$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range)
   # Attempt to pull xdivs from x.major in ggplot2 < 3.3.0; if NULL, pull from the >= 3.3.0 slot
   x.divs <- pbuild$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.major %||% pbuild$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$break_positions()
   x <- data.frame(group = sort(x = group.use), x = x.divs)
   ...
}
```

As a workaround to bypass the error try:

```
DoHeatmap(B_cells, features=tfs, label=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. It turns out that there was a problem with my cluster labeling, where one of my clusters ended up with an empty label (""). I found it by when I asked for DimPlot with label=T, and one of the clusters did not have a label. When I went back and re-labeled the clusters correctly, the DoHeatmap error disappeared.